# Missing XSSFWorkbook even after using Maven dependency poi-ooxml

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, pom.xml

Let me start by saying that I have seen a lot of questions regarding the error `XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type`. However, I have looked into most of them, and the accepted answer seems to be to add the Maven dependency poi-ooxml. Indeed, this is supported by the information on the Apache POI [official site](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components).

However, this is still not working for me. All the answers that I have seen so far used quite older versions. I fear that the answer might be different for the current ones.

Another interesting thing is that I was using the jar manually before, and I didn't experience any issues. However, when trying to import it as a Maven dependency, `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` seems to be the only import that it's missing.

Ps: I've also tried to use poi-ooxml-full and poi-ooxml-schemas, but none of it worked.

## pom

```pom
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>s6-night-shift</groupId>
  <artifactId>s6-night-shift</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>15</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j2html</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2html</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <type>pom.sha512</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: could you try removing  `<type>pom.sha512</type>` ? this will get you a pm.sha512 file instead of a jar

Comment: @PJFanning Ohh, wow, it worked! Any idea on why using Maven through Eclipse would add that line by default? Any chance I can disable it for future uses? Ps: Also, if you'd be so kind as to put that in an answer so that I can accept it ;)

Comment: absolutely no idea - always a good idea to read the code that IDEs generate to check that nothing weird was added

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another Apache dependency in your pom.xml file. Prefarably something like this below. This is so because both depencies are needed for Apache POi `XSSFWorkbook` class to be resolved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```